# How to customize drop-in UI with the AWSMobileClient?

Tags: swift, amazon-web-services

I currently have the correct code to customize the drop in UI straight from the iOS SDK docs. However it runs but is still the default AWS look. I have browsed profusely for the solution but to no avail.

```
import UIKit
import AWSAuthCore
import AWSAuthUI
import AWSMobileClient

class SignInViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        showSignIn()
                        //
                    AWSMobileClient.default().initialize { (userState, error) in
                               if let userState = userState {
                                   switch(userState){
                                   case .signedIn:
                                   self.createAlert(title: "You are already signed in!", message: "Sign out first")
                                           DispatchQueue.main.async {

                                              // self.signInStateLabel.text = "Signed out"
                                       }
                                   case .signedOut:
                                       AWSMobileClient.default().showSignIn(navigationController: self.navigationController!, { (userState, error) in
                                               if(error == nil){       //Successful signin
                                                   DispatchQueue.main.async {
                                                   //    self.signInStateLabel.text = "Logged In"
                                                     //   self.signOutButton.isHidden = false
                                                    //   self.tableView.reloadData()

                                                   }
                                               }
                                           })
                                   default:
                                       AWSMobileClient.default().signOut()

                                   }

                               } else if let error = error {
                                   print(error.localizedDescription)
                               }
                           }

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }


    func showSignIn() {
        if !AWSSignInManager.sharedInstance().isLoggedIn{
            AWSAuthUIViewController.presentViewController(with: self.navigationController!, configuration: nil, completionHandler: {(provider: AWSSignInProvider, error: Error?) in
                if error != nil {
                    print("Error occured: \(String(describing: error))")
                }else{
                    //Sign in Successful
                    print("Logged in with provider \(provider.identityProviderName)with Token: \(provider.token())")
                }
            })
            AWSMobileClient.default()
                .showSignIn(navigationController: self.navigationController!,
                                 signInUIOptions: SignInUIOptions(
                                       canCancel: true,
                                       logoImage: UIImage(named: "MyCustomLogo"),
                                        backgroundColor: UIColor.red)) { (result, err) in
                                        //handle results and errors
            }
        }

    }

    func createAlert (title: String, message: String){
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.actionSheet)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertAction.Style.default, handler: { (Action) in
            alert.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        }))
        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

I try to customize it in **func showSignIn()**. I would like to customize this UI to my own preferences.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have the right idea with SignInUIOptions but might just need less code and in the right places.  Here's what's worked for me:

In AppDelegate:

```
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Initialize AWSMobileClient singleton
     AWSMobileClient.default().initialize { (userState, error) in
         if let userState = userState {
             print("UserState: \(userState.rawValue)")
         } else if let error = error {
             print("error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
         }
     }
     return true
 }
```

In ViewController:

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    if !AWSMobileClient.default().isSignedIn {
        showLoginScreen()
        return
    }
}

func showLoginScreen() {

    AWSMobileClient.default().showSignIn(
        navigationController: self.navigationController!,
        signInUIOptions: SignInUIOptions(
            canCancel: false,
            logoImage: UIImage(named: "MyLogo"),
            backgroundColor: UIColor.red,
            secondaryBackgroundColor: UIColor.red,
            disableSignUpButton: true)
    ) { (signInState, error) in
            if let signInState = signInState {
                print("Sign in flow completed: \(signInState)")
            } else if let error = error {
                print("error logging in: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
    }

}
```